# What is the equivalent of RegisterObject/QueueBackgroundWorkItem in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

In "System.Web" ASP.NET, background work can be registered via `RegisterObject`/`QueueBackgroundWorkItem` in order to take part on the shutdown sequence of IIS (complete with 90 second grace period), but I'm struggling to find the exact equivalent in ASP.NET 5.

Looking at the source for [`Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEngine`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/HostingEngine.cs#L32), I can see that it signals via `IApplicationLifecycle.ApplicationStopping` and `IApplicationLifecycle.ApplicationStopped` (between which it disposes the server and `PipelineInstance`), but there doesn't appear to be any room for the 90 second grace period that necessitates `RegisterObject` in the old API.

The IIS integration layer hasn't been open sourced yet (if ever), so it's difficult to see how that implementation maps things.

Am I missing an API? Should I be performing a blocking shutdown via `CancellationToken.Register()`? Is that something that has been left out of "v1 of vNext"?

Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd still like feedback from the ASP.NET team, but I just noticed that Hangfire chooses a blocking shutdown (with timeout) via `CancellationToken.Register()` (though it targets the Katana equivalent for detecting shutdowns).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created the below using the Katana-based Hangfire implementation as inspiration. It has no testing beyond checking that the shutdown code ran when IIS Express was terminated, but it works as a proof of concept.

The design here is obviously *not* for "fire and forget" tasks, since they could be triggered right before a shutdown. It does, however, work for something like an idempotent queue processor (assuming idle shutdown timeouts have been disabled)

```
public static class BackgroundServiceExtensions
{
    public static void UseBackgroundService(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder, Func<CancellationToken, Task> service)
    {
        var lifetime = (IApplicationLifetime)builder.ApplicationServices
            .GetService(typeof(IApplicationLifetime));

        var stoppingToken = lifetime.ApplicationStopping;
        var stoppedToken = lifetime.ApplicationStopped;

        // This, in particular, would need to be properly thought out, 
        // preferably including an execution context to minimise threadpool use  
        // for async-heavy background services
        Task serviceTask = Task.Run(() => service(stoppingToken));

        stoppedToken.Register(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Block (with timeout) to allow graceful shutdown
                if (!serviceTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
                {
                    // Log: Background service didn't gracefully shutdown. 
                    //      It will be terminated with the host process
                }
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                // Ignored
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Which can then be used like so:

```
app.UseBackgroundService(async cancellationToken =>
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tick...");

        try
        {
            // Use cancellationToken for anything that is (logically) cancellable
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch(TaskCanceledException)
        { }
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cancellation requested, shutting down...");
});
```