# Send email async: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I'm trying to send email from a Controller asynchronous and getting the following error:

I **don't** want to wait email be sent to complete the action.

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending.

This is my implementation: I also tried using `void` instead `async Task`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
        {

            //dont want to await result
            //just send email 
            _mailService.SendAccountConfirmationEmailAsync(user);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    return View();
}
```

.

```
public async Task SendAccountConfirmationEmailAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    dynamic email = GetAccountConfirmationEmailTemplate();

    email.Username = user.Email;
    email.Name = user.UserName;
    email.To = user.Email;
    email.AccountConfirmationUrl = await GetAccountConfirmationUrl(user);

    await _mailService.SendAsync(email);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This? `_mailService.SendAccountConfirmationEmailAsync(user);`

Comment: Look into [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen gonna try this, but will have to update 4.5.1 to 4.5.2

Comment: .NET 4.5.1 is no longer supported so that is a good idea anyway.

Comment: If it is a time consuming operation, you can consider to put it into a queue (eg. web job if you are on Azure). This way the responsibility of sending email is taken off the Web App. You can also add retry scenarios making it more resilient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the runtime can recycle your appdomain when it knows there are no more pending requests, starting tasks that you don't wait for is specifically not recommended, hence that message.

In particular, without this check you would have no guarantee this email would ever be sent since the entire appdomain could be yanked down around that task after your controller action returns.

Now in your case you might say that the loss of the email is acceptable, but the runtime doesn't know that it is *only an email*, it could very well be your database call that you've *forgotten* to wait for that would be prematurely aborted. Hence it just informs you that this is bad form.

Instead you got two options:

1. Wait for that task to complete, which you have specifically said you don't want to do
2. Inform the runtime that you're firing off a task that you specifically don't want to wait for, but *please oh please, don't yank out the appdomain before task has completed*

This last part is what [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636892(v=vs.110).aspx) is for.

In your case you would call it like this:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
    _mailService.SendAccountConfirmationEmailAsync(user));
```

Additionally, the method provides a `CancellationToken`, you should check if there is an overload of `SendAccountConfirmationEmailAsync` that accepts it. If not, and if this is your API, you should consider adding support for such tokens.

Please be aware that this mechanism is not meant for long-running threads or tasks, for that there are other more appropriate trees to bark up, but in this case it should be enough.

Comment: Word of caution, `HostingEnvironment` is [not available on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netcore-2.0). You need to implement your own thing [using `IApplicationLifetime`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676140/what-is-the-equivalent-of-registerobject-queuebackgroundworkitem-in-asp-net-5/27714453#27714453)

Answer (score 2):

You need to await your async call in order to avoid the error message, but then you'll need to wait for the email to finish sending before your action method returns (and a failure sending the email will cause your action method to error out).

```
await _mailService.SendAccountConfirmationEmailAsync(user);
```

If you ever see a method name that ends in -Async, check if that method returns a Task or Task. If it does, you need to await it.

If you have an async call that you don't want to wait for it to complete in this context, you'll get that error. If you want to continue processing, you'll need some method of sending this email in a background task. That might be that you have a separate application that handles emails, and you communicate with it via a messaging system like RabbitMQ. Or there are [ways to run code in the background directly in a website](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) such as Hangfire.

Comment: He doesn't want to wait for it.

Comment: No, that is obvious, but that **is** the reason for that message. So like it or not, he has to deal with it.

Comment: @SLaks Ah, I missed that line in his question. I'll update my answer to explain "fire and forget" better.